# Casting fftw_complex pointer (aka double[2]) to cython complex memoryview

Tags: cython, fftw

(Cross-posted from cython-users)

I am trying to use FFTW for some Cython code.  I am running into issues when trying to cast a pointer to a fftw_complex (a typedef to double[2]) to a complex memoryview, namely (minimal example)

```
cdef extern from "fftw3.h":
    ctypedef double fftw_complex[2]
    fftw_complex* fftw_alloc_complex(int N)

cdef foo(complex[::1] input):
    complex_ny = fftw_alloc_complex(input.size)
    (<complex[:self.ny]>complex_ny)[:] = input
    # actual call to FFTW follows
```

fails at the cast: "hmm.pyx:8:34: Pointer base type does not match cython.array base type" (perhaps it can't be expected for Cython to know that double[2] can be converted to complex but... what else can I do?)

PS: If someone has experience using the pyFFTW wrapper directly from Cython, I'm interested too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complaining that it the type of `complex_ny` isn't the same as `complex` (and it doesn't know the conversion). If you cast `complex_ny` to a `complex*` first, then assign the pointer to a memoryview it's happier:

```
complex_ny = fftw_alloc_complex(input.size)
cdef complex[::1] view_of_complex_ny = <complex[:input.size]>(<complex*>complex_ny)
view_of_complex_ny[:] = input
```

As I'm sure you're aware, this only works because you've made it so that `complex` and `fftw_complex` are the same size.

---

**Addendum**

Given that `fftw_complex` and `complex` have exactly the same memory layout, the easiest solution is just to tell Cython that the `fftw_` functions deal with `complex*` instead of `fftw_complex*`. It doesn't actually look at the C files to check this is true - it just uses it for type conversion and memory allocation (both of which it should be OK for)

```
cdef extern from "fftw3.h":
    complex* fftw_alloc_complex(int N)

def foo(complex[::1] input):
    cdef complex[::1] complex_ny
    complex_ny = <complex[:input.size]>fftw_alloc_complex(input.size)
    complex_ny[:] = input
```

(You do get a warning about incompatible pointer types during the C compilation step, but it's only a warning, and you know the types are actually compatible.)